# How Do I Get Started? what is some advice

Tags: armature

i've wanted to try 3d animation for a while so i installed, but the problem is it's too much. I have an older version of blender (2.79) which I had to install due the driver not supporting the modern versions. I've watched tutorials so I know bits and pieces and plus all the tutorials seem to be for the newer version which looks a lot more begginer friendlt than mine. there's so much complicated things that I don't understand and it's all just a mess. I keep messing up the UI and don't know how to revert it, the keyframes are confusing and i only know how to create them and nothing else. I've had expirience with 2d animation but 3d animation is so different. All i want is a starting point so I can understand the UI and controls and feel comforatable and not mess everthing up.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question is considered off topic here and was put on hold for being subjective and attracting opinion based answers, because there are no "right" or "wrong" answers and every suggestion is equally valid. For art critique, tips, artistic input, tutoring tips, or other opinion based suggestions it is best to ask over at [Blender Artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org/) or similar forums. If you can rephrase it to focus on objective questions or solving specific issues feel free to [edit] it so it can be reopened.

Comment: i hate stack extange so fucking much they closed my question for a stupid reason becuase of an unrealted post that did NOT answer my question. and when to open "has been closed" to see what it meant exactly it erased my response. also opinion is what i'll take any help at this point! WHY IS IT SO HARD TO GET STARTED IM SO STRESSED

Comment: @user267509 Your question is much too broad for Blender Stack Exchange, you need to ask precise technical questions, you should better ask on BlenderArtists, but even there you'll need to be more specific

Comment: My best advice would be, take a break, have a snack, cool your head off a bit. Because you seem really tense right now, and it's not a good condition to learn anything. Then second advice is, **take it slow**. You don't need to (and frankly you can't) learn everything at once. Don't expect to be animating full humans in an hours. Go easy, start with UI basics, get comfy moving around in the viewport and exploring the different editors. Then animate a cube moving around.

Comment: @L0Lock that's a good idea I actually am a bit more expirienced with blender than i was before knowing more about some very important things about the timeline and interface and all that stuff. at the time i made this post i was very stressed and had less understanding so that's why it's a kind of bad, but i know to just quit when i get to annoyed and not rant about in stack extange